# Django cache framework not working with django-cms

Tags: django, django-cms, django-cache

I am using `django 3.1` and the [database caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/cache/#database-caching) and it is working properly, but when I included the `django-cms` in the project and ran `python3 manage.py createcachetable` as per the document of the cache framework it's giving an error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
 psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "abc_cache_table" does not exist
 LINE 1: SELECT "cache_key", "value", "expires" FROM "abc_cache_t...
```

the cache table is getting created without django-cms, but not working with it.
Is there any config that I am missing to add? any help and suggestion will appriated.

Thank you.

Comment: did you follow the documentation and run the command

Comment: yes, the cache table is getting created without `django-cms`, but not working with it